# Trigger a full height container when a minimum window width is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, resize

I am trying to implement a full height slideshow on my website. However, I would like the slideshow to be full height if the browser width is more than 767px.

This is my code so far:

```
if( $(window).width() > 767) {

  $(window).resize(function() {

   var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
   var headerHeight = $(".navbar").height(); 
   $('.slideshow, .slideshow li').height(winHeight);


  });

  $(window).trigger('resize');

}
```

It kinda works if I the browser starts on a width greater than 767. However. If if the browser starts on a width less than 767 and I start resizing more than 767, the script does not starts.

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: is that code on the `resize` event on the browser or just runs once in the beginning?

Comment: @jkris I'm not sure about the question but from what I think I think the resize trigger should always be running since it resizes the div every time the browser window is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resize` event handler is bound when your browser starts up **only** when `width > 767`, try removing the if condition and it should work fine

EDIT:

To make it apply only when it's width is > 767, the condition should be inside the `resize` event

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() > 767) {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var headerHeight = $(".navbar").height(); 
    $('.slideshow, .slideshow li').height(winHeight);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow, .slideshow li').height(400); //initial height
  }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: The thing is that I only want the .slideshow div to be the full height of the browser when when the browser width is more than 767 so I need the "if" in order to trigger it.

Comment: sorry, didnt quite read your requirements fully, updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @jkris. However when using your code no height is being calculated or applied to the .slideshow div

Comment: there was a syntax error on the code, updated it. it was the `()` on the if condition

Comment: Nice, almost there. Nothing is triggered when the browser width is less than 767 (good!). But if the width is larger, the only way the calculation will trigger is if I resize the browser. In other words, it won't fire automatically if the width is already 767 or larger.

Comment: haha okay, add `$(window).trigger('resize');` as you initially did after binding the function, updated my answer.

Comment: Wow thanks! One more thing (and sorry to bother, this is an entire lesson I'm getting here). Right now it works like this. If browser width is opened in less than 767px, nothing happens (good). If the browser width is opened in more than 767px it works (the trigger works). However, if I then resize to a width less than 767px the trigger is still active. Is there a way to deactivate the trigger if it was initially active on a width greater than 767px?

Comment: Well, you don't have to deactivate `trigger` because what it does is it fires the function on the `resize` event **once**. Maybe what you want to is to fire only if its at a right width but for what purpose? If you think it may reduce performance consider the `resize` event you created, it's being fired each time you resize your browser a pixel ( well maybe not every pixel but you get what i mean )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100328/discussion-between-johann-and-jkris).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this much more easily in css with a media query.

```
@media (min-width:500px){
  .slideshow{
    height:100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand your point but there's content after the slideshow so height: 100% is not going to work for this purpose. That's why I'm trying a JS alternative.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your meaning when you said 'full height'. I still think you're throwing js at a css problem which can lead to some nasty code smells. Best of luck.